# For some finitely many nonzero prime ideals, the contraction and extension of their product is zero

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, noetherian

I was reading P.M. Eakin's thesis paper, *The converse to a well known theorem on Noetherian Rings*. The following is taken from Theorem 2, page 281 of that paper, and that's where I'm stuck.

> Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ a finite integral overring of $R$. Suppose that $S$ is Noetherian and not an integral domain. If every prime ideal of $S$ contracts to a nonzero prime ideal of R, then for some nonzero prime ideals $P_{1},P_{2}, ... , P_{n},$ of $R$, $(P_{1}...P_{n})^{ec}=0$, where $e$ and $c$ are extension and contraction of ideals, respectively.

I have no idea how to prove it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** In a noetherian ring every ideal contains a product of prime ideals.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I don't know why,but I kept thinking that your hint holds for nonzero ideals only. I must be really tired.